# Skip image loading by selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara, selenium-webdriver

How to skip image loading using selenium webdriver for cucumber test cases. My test cases are failing due to image is not loading properly. a spinner a rolling when i see in Net tab in firebug.

Answer (score 2):

FirefoxDriver supports [loading strategy that doesn't require page to fully load](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#-Beta-_load_fast_preference). Thus driver will return without waiting for images to load:

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['webdriver.load.strategy'] = 'unstable'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, profile: profile)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :firefox
```